# Composer - adding git repository without composer.json

Tags: git, composer-php

I try to add repository from github (designmodo/Flat-UI), play with config and get errors `No valid composer.json was found in any branch or...`, `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`, `The requested package designmodo/flat-ui could not be found in any version`

What mistake I made in config:

```
"repositories": {
   "flat-ui": {
     "type": "package",
     "package": {
       "name": "designmodo/Flat-UI", 
       "version": "1.3.0", // Don't know is it important? Where get this number in repo?
       "source": {
         "url": "https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI",
         "type": "git",
         "reference": "dev-master" // reference is branch name? 
       }
     }
   }
 },

 "require": {
   "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "~3.2",
   "designmodo/Flat-UI": "dev-master" // branch again (/minimum-stability?)
 },
```

At some point composer download package but return error (i don't know when he did it, I lookup in vendor folder and designmodo folder was be there).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Problem solved. Play around and changed `reference` to `master` and version to any `*` in `"designmodo/Flat-UI": "*"` section. After that composer download package via git and update `composer.lock` without problems. Should work for any github repos.

**Working config:**

```
{
    "repositories": {
      "flat-ui": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
          "name": "designmodo/Flat-UI",
          "version": "1.3.0",
          "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "require": {
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "~3.2",
        "designmodo/Flat-UI": "*"
    },
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: This helped me a lot. This may be obvious, but `name` needs to have "a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name" (according to a deprecation warning generated by Composer). `version` needs to be a valid version string (like 1.0.0), though it can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 9):

It only worked for me removing the label, like this:

```
{
        "repositories":[
        {              
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "designmodo/Flat-UI",
              "version": "1.3.0",
              "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
              }
            }
        }
        ],
        "require": {
            "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "~3.2",
            "designmodo/Flat-UI": "*"
        }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: Beside adding a Git repository, I also wanted to include a SVN repository (that has no `composer.json`) and a ZIP file. The solution above did not work for me.

With Composer (version 1) I got following error message:

> Problem 1 - The requested package XXX could not be found in any
> version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Upgrading to Composer version 2 helped, since the error message was much more helpful:

> Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires XXX *, found XXX[master] but
> it does not match your minimum-stability.

So the solution is to [add "@dev" behind the required version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086204/composer-required-packages-with-differing-levels-of-minimum-stability). Furthermore, I had to include `"secure-http": false` to the `config` section, because the ZIP file comes from a page that has no HTTPS.

Here is my full `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "prefer-dist": true,
    "repositories": {
            "viathinksoft/vnag": {
                    "type": "package",
                    "packagist.org": false,
                    "package": {
                            "name": "viathinksoft/vnag",
                            "version": "master",
                            "license": "Apache-2.0",
                            "source": {
                                    "url": "https://svn.viathinksoft.com/svn/vnag/",
                                    "type": "svn",
                                    "reference": "trunk/"
                            }
                    }
            },
            "dcodeio/bcrypt.js": {
                    "type": "package",
                    "packagist.org": false,
                    "package": {
                            "name": "dcodeio/bcrypt.js",
                            "version": "master",
                            "license": [
                                    "BSD-3-Clause",
                                    "MIT"
                            ],
                            "source": {
                                    "url": "https://github.com/dcodeio/bcrypt.js",
                                    "type": "git",
                                    "reference": "master"
                            }
                    }
            },
            "spamspan/spamspan": {
                    "type": "package",
                    "packagist.org": false,
                    "package": {
                            "name": "spamspan/spamspan",
                            "version": "master",
                            "license": "GPL-2.0-only",
                            "dist": {
                                    "url": "http://www.spamspan.com/releases/spamspan-latest.zip",
                                    "type": "zip",
                                    "reference": "master"
                            }
                    }
            }
    },
    "require": {
            "dcodeio/bcrypt.js": "*@dev",
            "viathinksoft/vnag": "*@dev",
            "spamspan/spamspan": "*@dev"
    },
    "config": {
            "secure-http": false,
            "preferred-install": {
                    "*": "dist"
            }
    }
}
```

I would also like to explain why I am doing this:
These are examples of three third-party products which do not have `composer.json` file. I am aware that "bcrypt.io" is a `npm` project, and I could theoretically use `npm` to download it, and I could manually download and unpack the ZIP file in the `postinstall` part of composer.
However, I would like to have all dependencies in the `vendor` directory of my project, but I don't want to manually add something in this directory, because it is managed by composer. So I let composer handle everything.