# Laravel 5 package installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, installation

I want to install a laravel package but don't have any idea how to do it. 
It is the Admin Architect package that I want to install.

http://docs.adminarchitect.com/Getting_Started

This is the getting started page, if you scroll down to **Zip archive (Public way)** you will see the installation.

They say that you have to extract it in the package directory. But I do not have a package directory in my laravel 5.1 project.

Does someone know if you have to make one and put all the files that I have in there?

Comment: Use the instructions from the **Install Package** section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start at the `Via Zip archive (Public way)` section.

The way to do this is completely up to you.  The best way is probably to create a packages folder in your main Laravel directory along with `app`, `bootstrap`, `database` directories etc...

Unzip the contents of the zip package and then add the required item to your repositories in your `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
    ...
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "./packages/administrator"
    }
    ...
]
```

This will add the repository which contains the package `terranet/administrator` as long as the url is correct.  You might have to modify it to get it to work correctly so that when you run `composer require terranet/administrator`, it will be able to actually find `terranet/administrator` from the repository.

From there, simply follow the rest of the instructions (adding the service provider, etc...).

The reason other answers are not working is because the package `terranet/administrator` is not available publicly and you need to add the repository to your composer.json file for that to become availble.  You can see all packages available publicly by going to `packagist.org` where you will see searching for this package yields some results but not the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working. I thought that there already was a laravel packages directory and didn't know that I have to create one by my self. The other answers are also correct as they say the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you have composer installed you could run the following from your program directory:

```
composer require terranet/administrator
```

After the package installed, add a new service provider to the providers array in config/app.php file.

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Terranet\Administrator\ServiceProvider::class
]
```

Then, publish package's assets by running:

`php artisan vendor:publish`

OR

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Terranet\\Administrator\\ServiceProvider`

to publish only administrator's files.

Optionally you can run

`php artisan administrator:create`

to create new administrator user ->All this taken from the link you provided.

**Update**

The problem with minimum stability can be fixed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23086204/3664960) link for reference:

Tell composer you want to use stable whenever possible:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true
```

This basically means it will always use stable UNLESS there is no way to install a stable dependency, and therefore use dev.

Comment: I did the composer require command but got an error, see my updated post

Comment: It's not an issue with minimum stability.  It's an issue with that package not being available from packagist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you missed the instruction on the documentation:

**Open your terminal:**

```
 cd yourproject
```

then run:

```
 composer require terranet/administrator
```

**Add service provider in config/app.php file.**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Terranet\Administrator\ServiceProvider::class
]
```

**Run this command to publish assets:**

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

OR

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Terranet\\Administrator\\ServiceProvider to publish only administrator's files.
```

Optionally to create new administrator user run:

```
php artisan administrator:create
```

**Finally open config/administrator.php and make settings**